# JQuery Mobile and Knockout Integration -- Slider Is Created but is not functional

Tags: jquery, mobile, knockout.js

Basic problem is that slider created from JQuery Mobile within Knockout template is not functional.  The slider does not slide.

I have created the following jsFiddle examples to illustrate my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/fdoub/YEUgw/   -- sliders with Colors are not functional
http://jsfiddle.net/fdoub/YEUgw/1/ -- workaround that I came up with

I have checked other stackoverflow posts and not found any solution.
I have tried knockout bindingHandlers and JQuery mobile .refresh with no success.

This is my first stackoverflow post so be gentle if I have not done it perfectly.

Thank you one and all for all your invaluable advice.

**Non-Working Example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slider Problem</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h4>Slider Sample</h4>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Working Slider</p>
            <select name="slider" class="flip-a" data-role="slider">
                <option value="off">Off</option>
                <option value="on">On</option>
            </select>
            <span>Label Value</span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>Non-Working Sliders</span>
            <div data-bind="foreach:colors" style="visibility: visible;">
                <select name="slider" class="flip-a" data-role="slider">
                    <option value="off">Off</option>
                    <option value="on">On</option>
                </select>
                <span data-bind="text:$data"></span>
                <br />
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
$('#page1').on('pageinit', function () {
  var viewModel = {
      colors: ko.observableArray(["Green", "Blue", "Red"]),
  };
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Made it work by changing the javascript to**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//turn off slider creation
$.mobile.slider.prototype.options.initSelector = ".nosliders";

$('#page1').on('pageinit', function () {
  var viewModel = {
      colors: ko.observableArray(["Green", "Blue", "Red"]),
  };
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

//manually create sliders
  $(".flip-a").slider({
   create: function(event, ui) { }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expered in Knockout but you can create a bindinghandler like this:

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.jSlider = {
                                    init: function(element) {
                                             $(element).slider({ create: function(event, ui) { }});
                                            }                                                            
  };
```

Then every element with data-bind="{jSlider:true}" will invoke the init method and create your slider.

check out [this](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=custombindings) for more information.

Comment: Yep, using a custom binding like this is the best way to proceed in this case. There's a slight error in your example, though: the binding should look like this: data-bind="jSlider:true".